# Deploy Springboot TCP APP on PWS

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, deployment, cloud-foundry, tcpserver

Trying to deploy SpringBoot TCP server application on Pivotal Web Service(Cloud Foundry)

The following is in `manifest.yml` file

```
applications:
- name: myapp-api
  path: target/myapp-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  host: app
  domain: cf-tcpapps.io
  memory: 1G
  instances: 1
```

When i `cf push` i get this error

```
FAILED
Server error, status code: 400, error code: 310009, message: You have exceeded the total reserved route ports for your organization's quota.
```

when i `cf router-groups` i get

```
FAILED
Failed fetching router groups.
Server error, status code: 401, error code: UnauthorizedError, message: You are not authorized to perform the requested action
```

How can one deploy a spring mvc api that exposes a TCP port

Answer (score 2):

The PWS docs indicate:

```
Note: By default, PWS only supports routing of HTTP requests to applications.
```

This implies maybe they do, if you get a special dispensation? May be worth contacting PWS support.

Comment: As you are specifically asking about PWS, this is the correct answer.  Please email support@run.pivotal.io and indicate that you need a TCP route for your application.  They'll be able to set you up with one.

Answer (score 0):

The `cf router-groups` command is an admin-only command.
If `cf domains` returns the `cf-tcpapps.io` domain, a router group has already been set up, but your org or space has not been given permission (i.e., a quota of available TCP ports) to use it.
Ask your platform operator/admin. They may be able to increase your quota, or create a new TCP domain for you to use.

Comment: I am the one who created the account, no other person is involved